# Problems with automatically registering some models in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a base model that looks like this:

```
...
from core.admin import TimeStampedNamedAndDescriptionAdmin

class EditableNameAndDescriptionModel(NameAndDescriptionModel, TimeStampedModel):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta(NameAndDescriptionModel.Meta):
        abstract = True
        admin_class = TimeStampedNamedAndDescriptionAdmin
```

and a model that's extending this one:

```
class Kebab(EditableNameAndDescriptionModel):

    class Meta(EditableNameAndDescriptionModel.Meta):
        verbose_name = _("Kebab")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Kebabs")
```

I'm trying to automatically register all models that has `Meta.admin_class` defined using this in `urls.py` (since the app registry is loaded here)

```
from core.admin import auto_register_models
...
auto_register_models()
```

**admin.py**

```
def auto_register(model):
    if hasattr(model._meta, "admin_class"):
        field_list = [f.name for f in model._meta.get_fields() if f.auto_created == False]
        model_admin = type("AutoRegisteredAdmin", (model._meta.admin_class,), {'list_display': field_list})
        try:
            admin.site.register(model, model_admin)
        except AlreadyRegistered:
            pass


def auto_register_models():
    for model in apps.get_app_config('core').get_models():
        auto_register(model)
```

based on this:
https://technowhisp.com/auto-registering-models-in-django-admin/

The models get registered, but this is what it looks like in `Django` admin. It doesn't matter whether I use `model._meta.admin_class` or `ModelAdmin` in the code above. The results are the same.

[image: models without links]

just black text without any links to the models. And the URL for the model `(/core/kebab/)` just gives me a `404`.

If I run this in `admin.py` the models get registered as expected:

```
def auto_register(model):
    field_list = [f.name for f in model._meta.get_fields() if f.auto_created == False]
    model_admin = type("AutoRegisteredAdmin", (ModelAdmin,), {'list_display': field_list})
    try:
        admin.site.register(model, model_admin)
    except AlreadyRegistered:
        pass

for model in apps.get_app_config('core').get_models():
    auto_register(model)
```

But if I, import, in my EditableNameAndDescriptionModel:

```
from core.admin import TimeStampedNamedAndDescriptionAdmin
```

I get:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

It feels like some kind of Catch 22 here. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This occures, because you try to import something which hasnt been loaded in the memory,

a bit ugly but it will work

```
class EditableNameAndDescriptionModel(NameAndDescriptionModel, TimeStampedModel):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta(NameAndDescriptionModel.Meta):
        from core.admin import TimeStampedNamedAndDescriptionAdmin # import it here 
        abstract = True
        admin_class = TimeStampedNamedAndDescriptionAdmin
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've tried this import before. With poor results. I couldn't remember the exact problem, but I get: `TypeError: 'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): TimeStampedNamedAndDescriptionAdmin` when I try this.

I guess one (fairly) bad option is to use a string for the admin class, a la: "core. TimeStampedNamedAndDescriptionAdmin" and import it by the string?